# Why is type of computed property Ref<readonly string[]>?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

```js
type Items = string[]
const list = ref<Items>([])

const items = computed({
  get: () => list.value,
  set: (items: Items) => {
    list.value = items
  },
})
```

This is my computed property with a setter. My question is: Why am I returned a `Ref<readonly string[]>` when I provide a setter? I would expect items to have type `Ref<string[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#computed) is imprecise on `computed` types (it mentions `Ref<T>` instead of `Ref<Readonly<T>>`)  but explains the difference between readonly and changeable computed property:

> Takes a getter function and returns an immutable reactive ref object for the returned value from the getter.
>
> Alternatively, it can take an object with get and set functions to create a writable ref object.

The real types are:

```
export declare function computed<T>(getter: Option<T>['get']): Readonly<Ref<Readonly<T>>>;
export declare function computed<T>(options: Option<T>): Ref<Readonly<T>>;
```

`Ref<Readonly<string[]>>` type means that ref value can be reassigned like `ref.value = items` but not mutated like `ref.value[0] = item`.

Answer (score 0):

For this cases, you should use `WritableComputedRef<T>`, becouse, when we use only `ComputedRef` it's only for read, not for write.

E.g

```
let showMenu: WritableComputedRef<boolean> = computed({
  get: () => props.show,
  set: (value: boolean) => {
    ctx.emit("update:show", value);
  },
});

const handleEscape = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
  if (e.key === "Esc" || e.key === "Escape") {
    showMenu.value = false;
  }
};
```